# R heatmap on imported matlab table

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I would like to plot a heatmap on a table imported from MATLAB. The table has explicited rownames and colnames and I have loaded it into R with `read.table`, and I can run `summary(i)` and get the numeric summaries for each column:

```
i = read.table("file.txt",header=TRUE)
```

But when I try to run `heatmap`, it complains the converted matrix is not numeric, both with and without `rownames.force=TRUE`:

```
is.matrix(as.matrix(i,rownames.force=TRUE))
[1] TRUE

heatmap(as.matrix(i,rownames.force=TRUE))
 Error in heatmap(as.matrix(i, rownames.force = TRUE)) : 
   'x' must be a numeric matrix
```

I think the problem is that `as.matrix` tries to convert the non-numeric rowname (or colname, I am not sure anymore :-():

```
as.matrix(i)[1]
[1] "cluster-594-walk-0161"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add a reproducible example...

Comment: Could you also include a sample, say the first 5 lines, of your text file?

Comment: I find the `str` function very useful at times like this. Do `str(i)` to see if your matrix really contains what you think it contains in terms of variable types. `head(i)` also handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a reproducible example we are left guessing what goes wrong, but the error suggests that the matrix does not contain numbers but (probably) characters. Does this work:

```
i = as.numeric(i)
heatmap(as.matrix(i,rownames.force=TRUE))
```

and what is the output of:

```
is.numeric(as.matrix(i)[1])
```

(probably `FALSE`).

---

edit:
Your edit shows that the matrix contains characters, not numerics. It may be that in the text file the rownames are included as an additional column, probably the first one. In that case:

```
i = read.table("file.txt", header = TRUE, row.names = 1)
```

reads the first column as the rownames. So the problem is most likely in `read.table`, not in the conversion to a matrix.

Comment: This solved one problem, but it turns out I have non-unique entries in the input file:    i = read.table(file, header = TRUE, row.names = 1)
Error in read.table(file, header = TRUE, row.names = 1) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

Comment: You could read the file, throw away the first column, convert to numeric and than create the matrix. Do you need the row names as they are defined in the file?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simply rely on **defining the row names first** then **convert the data frame into matrix** then **inserting the raw names again**. it should work perfectly

```
rnames <- data[,1]    # assign labels in column 1 to "rnames"

mat_data <- data.matrix(data[,2:ncol(data)])  # transform column 2-5 into a matrix

rownames(mat_data) <- rnames                  # assign row names

heatmap.2(mat_data, col=redblue(256), scale="row", key=T, keysize=1.5, trace="none",cexCol=0.9,srtCol=45)   # your heatmap
```